# Confused on Kullback-Leibler divergence being invoked without proper definition

Tags: distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation, kullback-leibler, generative-models

I am trying to understand how authors of the [DDPM paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf) in appendix A, made the leap from equation 21 to equation 22.

Specifically, it is not clear to me how they managed to convert the first term of the first equation, into the kullback-leibler divergence (KLD) as the first term in the second equation, without "using up" the $\mathbb{E}_q$ on the outside of the brackets.

I don't even know how they got it to square with The [definition of the KLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) since the definition doesn't even match what's written here, because in the first term of the first equation, there is no $q(X_T | X_0)$.

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_q \left[ -\log \frac{p(X_T)}{q(X_T | X_0)} - \sum_{t>1} \log \frac{p_\theta(X_{t-1}|X_t)}{q(X_{t-1}|X_t, X_0)} - \log p_\theta(X_0|X_1) \right] \tag{21}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= \mathbb{E}_q \left[ D_{KL}(q(X_T | X_0) || p(X_T)) + \sum_{t>1} D_{KL}(q(X_{t-1}|X_t, X_0) || p_\theta(X_{t-1}|X_t)) - \log p_\theta(X_0|X_1) \right] \tag{22}
\end{equation}